# Evaluating $f(x) = 3x^2 - 2x + 4$ when $x = -2$

Tags: functions

\begin{align*}
f(x)& = 3x^2-2x+4\\
f(-2) & = ?
\end{align*}
I have tried solving it like this.
\begin{align*}
f(-2) & = 3(-2)^2-2(-2)+ 4\\
f(-2) & = 3 \cdot 4+4+4\\
f(-2) & = 12+4+4\\
f(-2) & = 20
\end{align*}

Is it right?

Comment: yes it's right.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: your calculations are ok

Comment: It is correct.  Is there a reason you were afraid it might not be?

Answer (score 1):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

You have correctly evaluated $f(x) = 3x^2 - 2x + 4$ when $x = -2$.